# Point one domain to another domain's subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I have an external domain (let's say MyGreatSite.com) and another domain with a subfolder (Let's say MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite). I'm wondering if it is possible to point MyGreatSite.com to MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite so that when users visit MyGreatSite.com they get the content of that subfolder, but it behaves as if they are on MyGreatSite.com, not MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite.

Basically I have some clients that have a new web site and we're wondering if it makes sense to just hijack the subfolder of the new site. It is wordpress based, if that makes any difference.

Both sites are hosted/managed on separate hosts.

Comment: are both domains pointing to the same document root? Meaning that, going to **mygreatsite.com** is same as **myhostingsite.com** ?

Comment: No. MyHostingSite.com will be its own site. I would just like to make that one specific directory /mygreatsite be linked to MyGreatSite.com so when  you're viewing MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite/about-us the you're seeing MyGreatSite.com/about-us in the URL bar.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're hoping:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MyGreatSite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite [P]
```

Comment: So that will be in the .htaccess of my root on MyHostingSite.com, and I simply point the nameservers for MyGreatSite.com over to MyHostingSite.com?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. Put that in the root of MyGreatSite.com, that way the traffic going there will display the content on MyHostingSite.com/mygreatsite.

Comment: MyGreatSite.com doesn't have hosting. It's just a floating domain name.

Comment: Do you have access to the apache configuration files on that server that is hosting MyHostingSite.com?